# How to write an equation like this in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I am not able to write this equation in LaTeX

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Which is your specific problem? The product symbol?

Comment: Yes, and how to add the range in that product symbol like r=1, r not equal to i to m

Comment: Since you have been a member of this site for two years, you should be able to create a minimal example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that. Remember to add it not to have your question downvoted next time.

Answer (score 4):

The product symbol is reproduced with `\prod`, with the usual way for the indices (`^` and `_`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
C_i=\left(\prod^{m}_{r=1,r\neq i}\frac{-x_r}{x_i-x_r}\right)f(x_i)\times P
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]